# How to search multiple columns in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, full-text-search

I'm trying to make a search feature that will search multiple columns to find a keyword based match. This query:

```
SELECT title FROM pages LIKE %$query%;
```

works only for searching one column, I noticed separating column names with commas results in an error. So is it possible to search multiple columns in mysql?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use the AND or OR operators, depending on what you want the search to return.

```
SELECT title FROM pages WHERE my_col LIKE %$param1% AND another_col LIKE %$param2%;
```

Both clauses have to match for a record to be returned. Alternatively:

```
SELECT title FROM pages WHERE my_col LIKE %$param1% OR another_col LIKE %$param2%;
```

If either clause matches then the record will be returned.

For more about what you can do with MySQL SELECT queries, try the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: What is the params are the same value? Say, you are searching whether 'Steven' is in a first OR last name of a user? (Given that users is a table, last_name and first_name are columns.)

Comment: @HunterStevens In that case, see [this other answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365428/2908724).

Answer (score 64):

If it is just for searching then you may be able to use CONCATENATE_WS.
This would allow wild card searching.
There may be performance issues depending on the size of the table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: Be careful when joining on CONCAT -https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/10/16/be-careful-when-joining-on-concat/

Comment: This will yield wrong results when columns don't contain "keyword" in them but the concatenated string does, e.g. for `column1 = 'key'` and `column2 = 'word'`.

Answer (score 20):

If your table is `MyISAM`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    pages
WHERE   MATCH(title, content) AGAINST ('keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

This will be much faster if you create a `FULLTEXT` index on your columns:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX fx_pages_title_content ON pages (title, content)
```

, but will work even without the index.

Comment: This is good, but it only works on exact matches, a search for dogs won't return a page titled dog.

Comment: Nope, you can use wildcard  'dog*' to match 'dogs' and 'dog'. though you can not use '*dog' to get 'adog'. Only prepending wildcards is supported.

Answer (score 7):

1)

```
select *
from employee em
where CONCAT(em.firstname, ' ', em.lastname) like '%parth pa%';
```

2)

```
select *
from employee em
where CONCAT_ws('-', em.firstname, em.lastname) like '%parth-pa%';
```

First is usefull when we have data like : 'firstname lastname'.

e.g

- parth patel
- parth p
- patel parth

Second is usefull when we have data like : 'firstname-lastname'. In it you can also use special characters.

e.g

- parth-patel
- parth_p
- patel#parth

Answer (score 6):

Here is a query which you can use to search for anything in from your database as a search result ,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_customer 
    WHERE CustomerName LIKE '%".$search."%'
    OR Address LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR City LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR PostalCode LIKE '%".$search."%' 
    OR Country LIKE '%".$search."%'
```

Using this code will help you search in for multiple columns easily

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM persons WHERE (`LastName` LIKE 'r%') OR (`FirstName` LIKE 'a%');
```

Please try with above query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative I found at [dev.to/massivebrains](https://dev.to/massivebrains/mysql-searching-multiple-columns-at-once-without-like-1e17). It uses LOCATE and provides fast results. LOCATE is used to find the position of a string, and concate_ws uses the first string as a delimiter. So choose a delimiter that wouldn't appear in your search string (else false matches may occur due to column bridging). Below is an exact match search. for a "ends with" or "starts with" delete the relevant delimiter in the search string.

```
SELECT
    `title`
FROM `pages`
WHERE LOCATE('#'+'searchString'+'#', CONCAT_WS('#', '#',`searchColumn1`, `searchColumn2`, `searchColumn3`,'#')) > 0
```