# mysql select statement combination one to multiple

Tags: mysql

best way to do this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  `column` like '%abc% %xcdb%' OR  `column` like '%abc% %dfhj%'
```

Here the first variable remains same but the second one changes for lets say an array of 10 to 20
So a better and faster way to repalce this iterative (`column` like)

table design

```
<table >
<tr>
    <td>id</td>
    <td>column</td>
    <td>other</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1;</td>
    <td>fsyd,**abc**,jgd,**xcdb**,sdfr</td>
    <td>tom</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>wer,tyuy,dhjd,dbhd</td>
    <td>john</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3;</td>
    <td>asy,gtyt,bnhhs,**abc**,bgy,trdcv,**dfhj**</td>
    <td>colin</td>
</tr>
     <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>wer,**xcdb**,dhjd,**abc**,dbhd</td>
    <td>john</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

this query gives back the result of id (1 and 3) but not 4 as it checks for the sequence.
this is a correct select statement and gives back the result i want but i am only asking for a better way to do this.

Comment: Could you add a short example of what you mean with a sample table and a desired result?

Comment: Perhaps this Question link may be helpful to you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514548/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE  column like '%abc% AND (column like '%xcdb%' OR  column like '%dfhj%');` ? assuming `'%xcdb%'` occurs more than `'%dfhj%'`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are asking and the implication that order matters, you have two options:

1. Looping through a bunch of `LIKE` queries (as you are doing)
2. REGEX's

My understanding is there is a significant performance hit for regex in MySQL, but I cannot verify that firsthand. I will try and post an example of your query using a regex if you want it and I have a few minutes to test.

Should look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE  `column` REGEXP('.*abc.*((xcdb)|(dfhj).*)')
```

See proof in SQLFiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cd26/1