# How search across multiple MySQL columns?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a search engine and I'm having some problems. This is my code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `offerta` WHERE `text` LIKE '%".$sea."%' AND `regione`='$re'
```

Now it works. I want to search on several columns and filter results by category (`regione`).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `offerta` WHERE `titolo` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `text` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `nome` LIKE '%".$sea."%' AND `regione`='$re'
```

`regione = '$re'` is the category.

I want to use WHERE `titolo` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `text` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `nome` LIKE '%".$sea."%' AND `regione`='$re'

It works well until AND. When i use one time OR and AND, it works, but when i uses several time OR and AND it doesn't works.

I tried MATCH and AGAINST but same error keeps coming up.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514548/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: @Sam - The answer for that question is not the same as this scenario.

Comment: @user3062975 - do you get an error when you run that code? Or is it returning the wrong data? Please give us a little more information so that we can assist you.

Comment: madebydavid - It works well until AND. When i use one time OR and AND, it works, but when i uses several time OR and AND it doesn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem:

SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `offerta` WHERE `regione`='$re' AND (`titolo` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `text` LIKE '%".$sea."%' OR `nome` LIKE '%".$sea."%')

Now it works well.