# mysql two/three column treat as one and then LIKE search and order

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to treat two or three column treat (merge) as one column and search with `LIKE` keyword from that one column and ORDER result as desired?

my columns

```
| to_place   | from_place  | departure_place|
|:-----------|------------:|:------------: |
| Same       |    Place    |    Line     
| Rangpur    |    Dhaka    |    Chittagong   
| Badda      |    bogra    |    hello     
| Shyamoli   |    rajshahi |    mohammadpur      
| test       |    test1    |    adabor    
| another    |    test2    |    kurigram
```

so i want these 3 columns in one column in my `SQL` so that i can order them

Comment: Partial duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514548/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-mysql.

Comment: you may user inner queries for this. Inner query will concatenate the columns (as many you want to concatenate) and outer query will apply a like constraint.

Comment: What's the separator you would use for concatenation or just no separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT to_place as Location FROM yourtable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT from_place FROM yourtable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT departure_place FROM yourtable) as DERIVEDTABLENAME
ORDER BY 1
```

actually you can merely use UNION as UNION ALL would return the same city name if it was in more than one column. that wouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: not working. showing `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias` error and there are no `LIKE` keyword

Comment: why do you need such union all kinda thing? Can't we just concatenate?

Comment: I added the derivedtablename, it can be anything, sorry left it out. Beyond that are you telling me you don't know how to add a WHERE clause to to do the LIKE search?

Answer (score 5):

I've tried this and it is working.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`to_place`, `from_place`,`departure_place`) AS derived_place
FROM `yourtable`
HAVING derived_place LIKE '%search_value%'
ORDER BY derived_place;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Then why is this not the accepted answer?

Comment: @Jis Jose I have accepted an answer which more closure to my requirements. but your effort help me.

Comment: however my one of the requirement was "get top ordering column name"