# Get the column names matching a multiple column search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

For an application, I need to show search results based upon multiple columns. Searching in multiple columns is not that [hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514548/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-mysql), but I also want to know which column(s) the search query matches the text.

Imagine following 'Blabla' table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| column1                |  column2                  | column 3                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Animals are beautiful  | Some text regarding music | Vague statement about politics |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Music is not his thing | Green is a color          | Random gibberish about music   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Searching for the word 'music' would be as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM Blabla WHERE column1 LIKE '%music%' OR column2 LIKE '%music%' OR column2 LIKE '%music%';
```

But is there a way in SQL to show that matching columns would be `column2` for row 1 and `column1` + `column3` for row 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column1 LIKE '%music%' THEN 'Column1' ELSE '' END AS col1match,
       CASE WHEN column2 LIKE '%music%' THEN 'Column2' ELSE '' END AS col2match,
       CASE WHEN column3 LIKE '%music%' THEN 'Column3' ELSE '' END AS col3match
FROM Blabla
```

Comment: Accepted your answer as you were the first. Thx for your fast responses guys (also @Anton Gogolev and @sagi). Now I think about it, don't know why I didn't think about this...

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
select
  column1,
  column2, 
  column3,
  case
    when column1 like '%music%' then 'column1'
    when column2 like '%music%' then 'column2'
    when column3 like '%music%' then 'column3'
    else ''
  end as [column]
from Blabla where column1 like '%music%' or column2 like '%music%' or column3 like '%music%'
```

Not sure about how performant this actually is.

Comment: Isn't that what he wants? @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `CASE EXPRESSION` for indication columns :

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           CASE WHEN t.column1 LIKE '%music%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 as col_1_ind,
           CASE WHEN t.column2 LIKE '%music%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 as col_2_ind,
           CASE WHEN t.column3 LIKE '%music%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 as col_3_ind
    FROM Blabla t) s
WHERE 1 IN(s.col_1_ind,s.col_2_ind,s.col_3_ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
declare @t table(column1 varchar(100), column2 varchar(100),column3 varchar(100))
insert into @t values
('Animals are beautiful','Some text regarding music','Vague statement about politics')

,('Music is not his thing','Green is a color','Random gibberish about music')

;With CTE as
(
 select column1,column2,column3,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select null))rn from @t
)
select case when column1 LIKE '%music%' then 'column1 in row'+ cast(rn as varchar) end
,case when column2 LIKE '%music%' then 'column2 in row'+ cast(rn as varchar) end
,case when column3 LIKE '%music%' then 'column3 in row'+ cast(rn as varchar)
end
from cte
```