# multiple search on text box like nameid,firstname,lastname

Tags: .net, vb.net

first time on asking not that good coder  need help about search query that can search multiple data name on database

```
Private Sub Search()
    Dim MySQLConnection As New MySqlConnection("host=127.0.0.1; user=root; database=sample")
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MySQLConnection.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from instructor where (IID LIKE '%" & SearchBox.Text & "%')"
        Cmd = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySQLConnection)
        READER = Cmd.ExecuteReader
        If READER.Read() Then

            lbl_ID.Text = READER("IID").ToString
            lbl_College.Text = READER("College").ToString
            lbl_Dept.Text = READER("Department").ToString
            lbl_Last.Text = READER("Lastname").ToString
            lbl_Middle.Text = READER("Middlename").ToString
            lbl_Name.Text = READER("Firstname").ToString
            lbl_EMPstatus.Text = READER("EmploymentStatus").ToString
            lbl_EMPtype.Text = READER("EmploymentType").ToString

        End If
        MySQLConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySQLConnection.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2514548/how-to-search-multiple-columns-in-mysql

Comment: Try to use parameters instead of creating the query your own way.