# mysql return result from table related to other tables

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm trying to show result from table that related to many tables but my problem is that the query is return only one product that is on special what I want to return are both products products on special and also products that are not. 
My Php Query is :

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT p.product_id, p.price ,sp.date_end, f.percentage AS special_percentage , p.model, pd.name AS title, pd.description AS text, cd.name AS section, p.image, pd.tag, p.date_added AS created "
                ."FROM #__mijoshop_product AS p "
                ."JOIN #__mijoshop_product_special AS sp ON  p.product_id = sp.product_id "
                ."JOIN #__mijoshop_flordeco_product_special_percentage AS f ON sp.product_id = f.product_id "
                ."INNER JOIN #__mijoshop_product_description AS pd ON p.product_id = pd.product_id "
                ."LEFT JOIN #__mijoshop_product_to_store AS ps ON p.product_id = ps.product_id "
                ."LEFT JOIN #__mijoshop_product_to_category AS pc ON p.product_id = pc.product_id "
                ."LEFT JOIN #__mijoshop_category_description AS cd ON (pc.category_id = cd.category_id AND cd.language_id = {$language_id}) "
                ."LEFT JOIN #__mijoshop_category_to_store AS cs ON (pc.category_id = cs.category_id AND cs.store_id = {$store_id}) "
                ."WHERE (LOWER(pd.name) LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%' OR
                        LOWER(pd.description) LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%' OR 
                        LOWER(p.sku) LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%' OR ";

                        if( $model ) {
                            $query .= "LOWER(p.model) LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%' OR ";
                        }

                        $query .= "LOWER(pd.tag) LIKE '%" . $search_text . "%') "
                ."AND p.status = '1' "
                ."AND date(sp.date_end) >= date(NOW()) "
                ."AND p.date_available <= NOW() "
                ."AND ps.store_id = {$store_id} "
                ."AND pd.language_id = '" . $language_id . "' "
                ."GROUP BY p.product_id "
                ."ORDER BY {$order_by} "
                ."LIMIT ".$limit;

        $db->setQuery($query);
        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Comment: Please provide the final constructed query, sample data, expected result, and current result.

Comment: Your script is at risk for [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Learn about [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) the string is not safe!

Comment: This isn't MySQL, it doesn't use `#` prefix for temporary tables. I think that's SQL-Server.

Comment: Based on the functions being used, I'm not so sure it's SQL Server either

Comment: @Barmar it's mysql and joomla

Comment: To receive the best possible advice, I recommend that you: 1. Provide a minimal dbfiddle demo that expresses the issue so that volunteers can test and tefine their suggestions and 2. Post your Joomla-related questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange  -- a place where volunteers are immediately aware of what `#_` means and can help you to secure your query with query builder methods.  ...Also, this post is worth a read: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2514548/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the joins with `#__mijoshop_product_special` and `#__mijoshop_flordeco_product_special_percentage` to `LEFT JOIN` so that it won't restrict the results only to products that have matches in this table.

Also, you don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY p.product_id`; since there's only 1 row for each product ID, you can't get any duplicates. However, it also doesn't make sense to use `GROUP BY` when you're not using any aggregation functions, like `SUM()` or `COUNT()`. If all these tables are 1-to-1 correspondences, you shouldn't get any duplicates that need to be removed with either option.